# How to change the state of an entity if the same entity is contained in different collections of an entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to insert a new entity called Document:

```
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    

    public virtual ICollection<User> UsersOne { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> UsersTwo { get; set; }
}
```

The entity Document has two relationships many-to-many with the entity User:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

In my request, i send the following Json:

```
{
    "UsersOne": [{"Id": 1},{"Id": 2},{"Id": 3}],
    "UsersTwo": [{"Id": 1},{"Id": 2},{"Id": 3}],
    "Id": 0 
}
```

The problem is that i alredy have the users in the context, and when i add the entity document in the context `_context.Document.Add(entity);`, the entity insert the users in the context with the added state.

Maybe one solution is to change the state for unchanged:

```
foreach (var user in entity.UsersOne)
    _context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

foreach (var user in entity.UsersTwo)
    _context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

But when i do this, i have the following error

> Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type 'Entity.User' have the same primary key value. Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are unique.

I also tried to join the two collections into one, and change their states, but the context still have users with added state.

I also tried change users state to detached, before add the document to the context, but on `_context.SaveChangesAsync();`, a exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' is thrown, because the properties email and password are required to User.

Comment: I am also having the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. If the User entity is being created and added to two different lists, you have to create and save the User entity by itself first, then go back and add that newly created User to the two lists.
2. When you deserialize the JSON, you have to create a single User entity and add the same instance to both collections.  Otherwise, EF will think they are two different User entities with the same PK and throw that exception.  If you add the same instance to both, EF should recognize it is the same User and save correctly.

Finally, if you are saving this User entity with only an Id, you will get the required errors on Email and Password because you have the [Required] annotation on there.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your answer, based on her we found a solution. First we find the users in the context, then clear the relationship between user and document, then we set the found users to the document.